# SOAPClient API Issue

Tags: php, soap

I have just tried connecting up to an API (which utilises SOAP) via PHP and have run into an error. I have also just installed PEAR with the SOAP package - no experience with it so any guidance would be much appreciated! Thank you!!

> **Fatal error:** Class 'SoapClient' not
>   found in
>   /home/server/public_html/class_console.php
>   on line 19

Line 19 from class_console.php

```
if(is_null($proxyHost) || is_null($proxyPort))
$connection = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('login' => $username, 'password' => $password));
```

My API script includes;

```
// connection credentials and settings
$location = 'https://theapiurl.com/';
$wsdl = $location.'?wsdl';
$username = 'user';
$password = 'pass';
```

Answer (score 0):

its just telling you that SoapClient is not installed on your server.. check your php.ini i think the extension is called soap_php.so (or .dll on Win), or maybe it's php_soap.so

Comment: My php.ini file looks like this: max_execution_time = 0 extension=php_soap.so (I have also tried.dll with no luck)

Comment: be careful with the php.ini once i had a problem because the php client (from command line) might use a different php.ini than the apache server. Just to make sure, do a phpinfo() on your script and see if soap is enabled or not

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use the SOAP client from the PEAR package, but [NuSoap](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/) worked well for me.

Comment: Thanks. The API recommended PEAR but if it doesn't work soon I'll change to NuSoap.

Answer (score 0):

try Soap_Client rather than SoapClient